# Own Cloud Client update

Tags: updates

App Center shows me that 3 components can be updated:

• libowncloudsync0 the ownCloud sync library Version: 2.7.4+oc-2934
• owncloud-client-doc development files for the ownCloud sync lib Version: 2.7.4+oc-2934
• owncloud-client-l10n Internationalization files for ownCloud Version: 2.7.4+oc-2934

Unfortunately this doesn't work through the App Center.

When I call up

apt list --upgradable

in the terminal, I see

libowncloudsync0/unbekannt 2.7.4+oc-2934 amd64 [aktualisierbar von: 2.4.1+dfsg-1]
owncloud-client-doc/unbekannt 2.7.4+oc-2934 all [aktualisierbar von: 2.4.1+dfsg-1]
owncloud-client-l10n/unbekannt 2.7.4+oc-2934 all [aktualisierbar von: 2.4.1+dfsg-1]

Unfortunately, since I tried to update, the ownCloud program has also disappeared from the list of my installed programs.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the trail.

I think I had ownCloud installed as a snapt.

Now that I have installed the Snapt Store as a Snapt app, ownCloud is displayed as installed there.

Since I don't need the program (rather NextCloud) I uninstalled it there.

However, the three components that need to be updated are still displayed in the AppCenter. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

During the last system update, I removed the packages that were no longer needed via the terminal - the command for this was offered by the terminal. That's it